# Using GitLab API, how do I get a list of active users?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-api

Gitlab-CE v8.14.3

I'm reading the [GitLAB API docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/README.html), and am trying to get the list of active users. I'm an admin and created a personal token. I do this

```
$ curl -XGET "Private-Token: kfjakjfkjkd" https://company.domain.com/api/v3/users?active=true
```

and keep getting 401 (Unauthorized) error. Like I said, I'm an admin. What gives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify that `Private-Token: kfjakjfkjkd` is an HTTP header with `-H` :

```
curl -H "Private-Token: kfjakjfkjkd" https://company.domain.com/api/v4/users?active=true
```

Comment: As of current version (11.5 on march 19), the api version is v4 instead of v3, changing this is enough

Answer (score 13):

You must specify the header using the `-H` option as noted in Bertrand Martel's answer. That will retrieve up to 20 users.

Above 20 users, you must get fancier. [The JSON output is paginated](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/README.html#pagination), and each query is limited to 100 users per page. So to get 300 users, you must get three pages, 100 users at a time:

```
curl -H "Private-Token: kfjakjfkjkd" "https://company.domain.com/api/v4/users?active=true&per_page=100&page=1" > gitlabusers1.json
curl -H "Private-Token: kfjakjfkjkd" "https://company.domain.com/api/v4/users?active=true&per_page=100&page=2" > gitlabusers2.json 
curl -H "Private-Token: kfjakjfkjkd" "https://company.domain.com/api/v4/users?active=true&per_page=100&page=3" > gitlabusers3.json
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for as my user base is much higher than 100. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, just what I wanted! I thought that I'd add that if you ask for a page that doesn't exist (past pagination limit), then you get back `[]`